# Node.js: HTML as string parser

Tags: html, node.js, parsing

I'm trying to find a NodeJS library/package that can parse HTML with complex queries.

For example, for input:

```
var html-parser = require('magical-parser');
var htmlStr = '<div class="wrapper"><span id="spanny"></span></div>';

var parsedHtml = html-parser.parse(htmlStr);

console.log(parsedHtml.findById('spanny')); 
// prints <span id="spanny"></span>

console.log(parsedHtml.findByclass('spanny'));
// prints <div class="wrapper"><span id="spanny"></span></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) (*implementation of core jQuery designed specifically for the server*)

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var htmlStr = '<div class="wrapper"><span id="spanny"></span></div>';
var $ = cheerio.load(htmlStr);

console.log($('#spanny')); // get element by id 
console.log($('.spanny')); // get element by class
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Cheeriojs](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) to use jQuery in a parsed dom.  Here's some sample code.

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio'),
    $ = cheerio.load('<div class="wrapper"><span id="spanny"></span></div>');

console.log($('#spanny').text());
```